# Freeze scrolling on a jQuery list while list elements toward the top of the list are resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list, scroll

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Z4BY/3/) I've implemented a list with a click handler. When an element in the list is clicked the ".selected" class is added to it which changes it's height. When a different list element is subsequently clicked the ".selected" class is removed from the previously clicked element (thus restoring it to its original height) and the ".selected" class is added to the newly clicked element altering it's height.

Notice in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Z4BY/4/) that when a list element is clicked and the ".selected" element is below it in the list the clicked element stays perfectly still while it expands and the previously selected element contracts. However when a list element is clicked and the ".selected" element is above it in the list, the list scrolls up to compensate for the contracting element causing the newly ".selected" list element to move up a little. I would like some mechanism for smoothly mitigating this behavior so the ".selected" list element stays perfectly still in this circumstance.

Html:

```
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
 <li>6</li>
 <li>7</li>
 <li>8</li>
 <li>9</li>
 <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

css:

```
li{
    width:100%;
    border-top:solid black 1px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
}

.selected{
    height:300px;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: I see that you accepted my answer, many thanks. I don't want to seem impolite, but can I hope that I will get the bounty too?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tony. I think I just awarded it, let me know if it didn't go through. I'm surprised the bounty award isn't automatic with the answer acceptance.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is fine now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you need offset scroll so newly selected element stays in the view. I suggest the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function(){

        var $this = $(this),
            pos = $this.offset().top,
            $doc = $(document);

        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $this.addClass("selected");

        $doc.scrollTop($doc.scrollTop() + $this.offset().top - pos);
        console.log($this.offset().top - pos);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Z4BY/18/)

Answer (score 0):

To this point:

> I would like some mechanism for smoothly mitigating this behavior so
>   the ".selected" list element stays perfectly still in this
>   circumstance.

I don't see how you will be able to keep it "perfectly still" in that when the other item contracts if the rest of the list was somehow "fixed" into place then there would be a huge gap in between the items...

A couple of thoughts... this css:

```
li{
    width:100%;
    border-top:solid black 1px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    transition: height 2s;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s;
}

.selected{
    height:300px;
    background:red;
    transition: height 2s;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s;
}
```

Makes for a much less jarring transition that is easy for the eye to follow.

To actually get what you asked for, "perfectly still", you could do something derpy like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$("li").click(function(){
    $(".previouslySelected").removeClass("previouslySelected"); $(".selected").removeClass("selected").addClass("previouslySelected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
    });
```

CSS

```
.previouslySelected {
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:200px;
}
```

Which as you see does keep the one below from "jumping"... cuz I consider this a derpy approach I didn't take the time to check if the newly clicked one was above or below the previously selected one etc... but that would be trivial to add.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply add a transition to the `<li>` elements?
In this way you have a smooth effect between selected/not-selected states.

```
li{
    width:100%;
    border-top:solid black 1px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.selected{
    height:300px;
    background:red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Z4BY/20/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following jQuery stuff

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("li").click(function() {

     var selectItemTop = $(this).position().top;

     var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     var selectItemHeight = $(".selected").height();
     var selectionTop = $('li').hasClass('selected') ? $(".selected").position().top : 0;
     console.log(selectionTop);
     if (selectionTop < selectItemTop) {
       selectItemTop = selectItemTop - windowTop;
       $(window).scrollTop(windowTop + selectItemTop - selectItemHeight);

     }


     $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

     $(this).addClass("selected");


   });
```

I nearly managed to fulfill your requirement.

you can test example from this link **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zainabed/6Z4BY/21/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("li").click(function(){    
    var selectItemTop = $(this).position().top;    
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var selectItemHeight = $(".selected").height();
    var selectionTop =  $('li').hasClass('selected') ? $(".selected").position().top : 0;
    console.log(selectionTop);    
    if(selectionTop < selectItemTop){
      selectItemTop = selectItemTop-windowTop;
            $(window).scrollTop(windowTop+selectItemTop-selectItemHeight);        
    }
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");    
      });

    });
```